# Jenkins Job Builder Configuration in Python

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

While updating the Jobs in  Jenkins Job-Builder using `jenkins-jobs update` I'm getting the below error.

```
INFO:root:Updating jobs in ['jobs'] ([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jenkins-jobs", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cmd.py", line 191, in main
    execute(options, config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/cmd.py", line 372, in execute
    n_workers=options.n_workers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 348, in update_jobs
    self.load_files(input_fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/builder.py", line 293, in load_files
    self.parser.parse(in_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/parser.py", line 128, in parse
    self.parse_fp(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins_jobs/parser.py", line 105, in parse_fp
    cls, dfn = next(iter(item.items()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Job-Builder Version : 1.6.1
Python Version : 2.7
OS : RHEL 7.1

I've tried this in different machines but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`error is very common in python, it will be more helpful if you share the code or atlease where the error is appearing.

You are using "Jenkins Job Builder" for configuring jenkins and you are getting error while updating jenkins jobs. The `update` command is used to deploy the job to jenkins after you have tested the job definition. The `update` command requires a configuration file.

You should pass that configuration file as it is, not in string format and also the jobs should be in non string format inside configuration file, I mean not in `'` OR `"` single or double quotes.

Comment: Below are the file config we are using

jenkins_jobs.ini file configuration
`[job_builder]
ignore_cache=True
keep_descriptions=False
include_path=.:scripts:~/git/
recursive=False
exclude=.*:manual:./development
allow_duplicates=False

[jenkins]
user=jenkinsuser
password=6851ab76b48ceabd2e07822241f23cad
url=https://jenkins.test.com
query_plugins_info=False

Yaml file configuration
- job
        name:JJB_Test
        description:Automatically generated Job
        project-type:freestyle`
-- We have tried the above method but still getting the same error.
Thanks in advance